# How can I locate GameObjects near the player in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to figure out how I can find GameObjects that are close to the player so that I can delete them with `Destroy()`.  I know how to use `Destroy()` but I can't figure out how to get a reference to the objects I want to remove.

```
public class hand : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform player;
public Transform mushrums;
private Animator anim;

void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}
public void HandUp () {

    float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, mushrums.position);
    Debug.Log(dist);
    if (dist <= 59)  
    {
        anim.Play("pick_up");

            Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(this.transform.position, 20);

        while (i < hitColliders.Length) {
                 thisDist = (transform.position - hitColliders[i].transform.position).sqrMagnitude;

            if(thisDist < nearDist) {
                    nearDist = thisDist;
                    nearest = hitColliders[i].transform;

                }
            }
            if(nearest != null) {
            Destroy(nearest.gameObject);
            }

    }

}
}
```

if the radius of the 10, subject is not and
`hitColliders.Length = 0` 
if the radius of the 20 its freezing
if remove WhileLoop `while (i < hitColliders.Length) {thisDist ...` but keep `if(thisDist < nearDist) {...` everything works and get another object, not the one that is near
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to get a reference to a GameObject.  In your desire to locate objects near the Player, [`Physics.OverlapSphere()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) is likely what you are looking for.

The various Physics static methods will do similar things in terms of "find this thing" where "this thing" is a more abstract concept (e.g. "Find the object I'm looking at" would use [`Physics.Raycast()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to find an object directly under the mouse cursor), and in many cases, it will return *more than one* object and you can loop through the list and do something to either one of them (using some criteria to identify it) or all of them.

For example, this code will find the nearest object to the player and delete it.

```
void Update() {
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(this.transform.position, 10);

    Transform nearest = null;
    float nearDist = float.PositiveInfinity;
    for (int i = 0; i < hitColliders.Length; i++) {
        Vector3 offset = transform.position - hitColliders[i].transform.position;
        float thisDist = offset.sqrMagnitude;
        if(thisDist < nearDist) {
            nearDist = thisDist;
            nearest = hitColliders[i].transform;
        }
    }
    if(nearest != null) {
        Destroy(nearest);
    }
}
```

`Destroy()` will destroy GameObjects as if you selected them in the scene hierarchy and hit [Delete].  For most components, it would be like right-clicking on it in the Inspector and selecting "remove."  Transforms are different: Destroying a Transform will also delete the GameObject as a GameObject *requires* a Transform component, so removing one automatically removes the other.  I did this on purpose to illustrate this point, but it would have been perfectly valid to do `Destroy(nearest.gameObject)` as well.